# VBA Macro to fill the selection range with color from shape color

Tags: vba

I hide the toolbar, however need, fill the color menu. Whether possible to create a shape as the button with color and fill the selection shape into range selection cell from mouse

[image]

I have plane provide 3 different colors by using shape as a button, example Blue, Red and Black and if I select B:1 or A23 and click one of three colors shape the select range will fill by the same color. ( When I select range cell B:1 then click Red Shape, the cell B:1 will fill with Rd Color.

Comment: Update..I have plane provide 3 different colors by using shape as a button, example Blue, Red and Black and if I select B:1 or A23 and click one of three colors shape the select range will fill by the same color. ( When I select range cell B:1 then click Red Shape, the cell B:1 will fill with Rd Color )

Comment: You can edit your question to add the update there.

Comment: Thank you Vityata,I forgot due to I stress enough to find the same VBA Code from Internet however not found :(

Comment: I'm struggling to actually understand what your question is. Do you have code that you've tried so far?